# Nhibernate 3 Linq - inner joins

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm testing out nhibernate 3 CR, but fails to create the following SQL using Linq:

```
select   *
     from        Users               as {user}
     inner join  Test                as test  on test.UserId   = user.Id
     inner join  Release             as release on release.TestId = test.TestId
     where Release.Status = 1
     order by    count(release.Status) desc;
```

I have not got so far, my current code is like this and gives me something complete different:

```
var users = from user in Session.Query<User>()
            join test in Session.Query<Test>() on user.Id equals test.User.Id
            join release in Session.Query<Release>() on test.Id equals release.Test.Id
            where release.Status == 1
            orderby release.Status
            descending 
            select user;
```

Is there any resources on how to use inner joins with linq? And what should I do with:

```
order by    count(release.Status)
```

Is this something that should be done with QueryOver instead?

Comment: Why do you define relationships between entities in the queries instead of in the mapping?

Comment: I was just testing linq on a legacy application. So this is how the SQL looked like. I can smell a rewrite of the mappings, but the point here was to see how far Linq to nhibernate had evolved. And it looks like it's not very usable.

Answer (score 6):

First, define relationships in your model instead of trying to join by id.

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
from release in session.Query<Release>()
where release.Status == 1
select release.Test.User
```

All that's missing is the orderby, which I don't think is correct (you are trying to order by an aggregate, but you're not specifying a group by)

Comment: This causes to implicit outer join and is not efficeint as inner join

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, NH still doesn't support joins in linq well.
So better to use HQL, or even QueryOver (I think for simple queries it's the best). Look at this example:

```
// just to assign aliases, not for real use:
Test qtest = null;
Release qrel = null;

// do query
var data = Session.QueryOver<User>()
  .JoinAlias(quser => quser.Tests, () => qtest)
  .JoinAlias(quser => quser.Releases, () => qrel)
  .Where(() => qrel.Status == 1)
  .OrderBy(() => qrel.Status).Desc
  .List();
```